# How to move a gameObject From his position to another object position in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am Beginner in Unity Game engine.

i wanted to move an object from his position to position of other object.

Comment: `transform.position = otherObject.transform.position;` will do this instantaneously

Comment: @Renan you are right, but I leave my comment ;-)

Comment: @Kay Your comment is good enough to be an answer, actually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can move an object from its position to anothers with this following code

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(pos3, too3, step3);
```